# Tensorflow Serving does not return Base64 Encoded Image

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, base64, tensorflow-serving

I deployed a Conv-Based Neural Network Architecture using Tensorflow Serving. I'm querying the Rest API, as expected, I send a Base64 Encoded image on the json body:

```
{'instances' : [{'b64': b64image}]}
```

Everything is working as expected, but, the json response from Tensorflow Model Server does not returns other b64 encoded image, but the raw jpg file bytes:

```
{'predictions': [imagebytes]}
```

This causes a lot of problems of course. I don't know what I'm missing, at first I was thinking the Model Server returns b64encoded image, it something expected because the Model Server automatically decodes b64 input in the request. How can I enable support for this?

Right now the solution I can think is wrapping my model to return b64encoded string (actually my model is already wrapped for taking as input raw image bytes and outputs raw image bytes)

Hope your suggestions!

PD: I decide to modify the exported model to output b64-encoded image string, this solves my problem for now, but surely this must have another approach, it is not logical that TF Serving supports Base64 Decoding for the input, but it does not Encode the Output the same way.

Comment: Hey there! What is your Code to modify the exported model to output a b64-encoded string? I can't get it working.

Comment: check this https://github.com/ElPapi42/deep-deblurring-model/blob/fa87954df3c27f4ae9a5ba0fc58f72124489a451/deblurrer/model/wrapper.py

Answer (score 0):

TF serving's output json response will consist of base64-encoded image. To grab our base64-encoded image from the JSON response, we have to access:

- The value corresponding to “predictions” in the response dictionary.
- The first entry in the resultant array.
- The value corresponding to “b64” in the resultant dictionary.

Then, we’ll decode that value to a raw bitstring. Ref: [Serving Image-Based Deep Learning Models with TensorFlow-Serving’s RESTful API](https://towardsdatascience.com/serving-image-based-deep-learning-models-with-tensorflow-servings-restful-api-d365c16a7dc4)

Example Code:

```
# Extract text from JSON
response = json.loads(json_response.text)

# Interpret bitstring output
response_string = response["predictions"][0]["b64"]
print("Base64 encoded string: " + response_string[:10] + " ... " + response_string[-10:])

# Decode bitstring
encoded_response_string = response_string.encode("utf-8")
response_image = base64.b64decode(encoded_response_string)
print("Raw bitstring: " + str(response_image[:10]) + " ... " + str(response_image[-10:]))

# Save inferred image
with open("images/sinusoidal.png", "wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(response_image)
```